# UIBezierPath containsPoint not working with touchesBegan

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

I'm drawing a filled shape using the UIBezierPath and i want to check if a user touches this shape. Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{ 
aShape = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:
 CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100)];

[[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];

CGContextRef aRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(aRef, 50, 50);

aShape.lineWidth = 5;

[aShape fill];
[aShape stroke];

 CGPoint x = CGPointMake(30, 40);
 if([aShape containsPoint:x]) {
 NSLog(@"in");
 } else {
 NSLog(@"out");
}
}
  - (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
}
return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
 [aShape dealloc];
[super dealloc];
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
 UITouch *t = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p = [t locationInView:self];
[aShape containsPoint:p];
}

@end
```

I have some issues with the :containsPoint method. It is working in the drawRect-Code, but not in the touchesBegan method and I don't know why :( I would appreciate some help...Thx.

Comment: Have you checked if the point in touchesBegan is really a point, and is valid? Try printing it to the debug console.

Comment: Yes did that. It is a point. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I had to venture a guess, it isn't working as you expect in touchesBegan because you're not accounting for the fact that you drew the path offset. `[aShape containsPoint:p]` isn't going to know about the context transform you applied previously.

On a slightly different note, `[aShape dealloc]` you should never call dealloc on an object directly. The only time you call dealloc is on super at the end of your own dealloc. This line should be `[aShape release]`

Comment: So, the only answer is redrawing the view on every touch? Thanks for your suggestion with dealloc.

Comment: Where did you get that from my answer? Take your transform, and apply it to the point. After that check if it is contained.

Comment: What do you mean by "apply it to the point"? I really don't get it. Do you mind giving me a small example?

Comment: p = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(p, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(50,50))

Answer (score 0):

For those having the same problem in Xamarin / MonoTouch, here is a similar solution:

```
public class FooControl : UIControl
{
    private float _xOffset;
    private float _yOffset;
    private UIBezierPath _path;

    public FooControl(RectangleF frame) : this(frame)
    {
        //offsets to move drawing origin to center of containing frame
        _xOffset = Frame.Width / 2;
        _yOffset = Frame.Height / 2;
    }

    public override void Draw(RectangleF rect)
    {
        base.Draw(rect);

        using(CGContext g = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext())
        {
             // move origin to middle of screen
             g.TranslateCTM(_xOffset, _yOffset);

             if (_path == null)
             {
                 _path = new UIBezierPath();

                //... build rest of path ...

                _path.Close();
             }

            //... rest of drawing code goes here ...
        }
    }

    public override UIView HitTest(PointF touchPoint, UIEvent uiEvent)
    {
        if (_path != null)
        {
            //important! to reverse original translation, use negative values
            CGAffineTransform affine = 
                CGAffineTransform.MakeTranslation(-_xOffset, -_yOffset);

            PointF localPoint = affine.TransformPoint(touchPoint);
            if (_path.ContainsPoint(localPoint))
            {
                return this;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```